# What is the difference between java.lang.String.getBytes (String charsetName) and java.lang.String.getBytes (Charset charset)?

Tags: android

Difference between `java.lang.String.getBytes (String charsetName)` and `java.lang.String.getBytes (Charset charset)`.

How to use `java.lang.String.getBytes (Charset charset)` in android api 8. Is there any alternate way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's the same.

Copied from the java source:

```
public byte[] getBytes(String charsetName)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (charsetName == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    return StringCoding.encode(charsetName, value, 0, value.length);
}

public byte[] getBytes(Charset charset) {
    if (charset == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    return StringCoding.encode(charset, value, 0, value.length);
}
```

To explain @Henry's answer:

```
static byte[] encode(String charsetName, char[] ca, int off, int len) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
         StringEncoder se = deref(encoder);
         String csn = (charsetName == null) ? "ISO-8859-1" : charsetName;
         if ((se == null) || !(csn.equals(se.requestedCharsetName())
                               || csn.equals(se.charsetName()))) {
             se = null;
             try {
                 Charset cs = lookupCharset(csn);
                 if (cs != null)
                     se = new StringEncoder(cs, csn);
             } catch (IllegalCharsetNameException x) {}
             if (se == null)
                 throw new UnsupportedEncodingException (csn);
             set(encoder, se);
         }
         return se.encode(ca, off, len);
}
```

Comment: Well, not really. `getBytes(String charsetName)` is likely a little slower since it has to look up the charset and it can throw a checked exception `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: @Henry Yes, it does. But it doesn't matter, since you have to get the `Charset` as well, if you would call the other method.

Comment: Not if you use one of the standard charsets (available since Java 7), for example `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`

Comment: Right, I forgot about this.

Comment: No, they are not the same.  Each code path calls a different static method of StringCoding class

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak The outcome is the same, if you look at my edit from last year. The String version has a little overhead, because it has to figure out which CharSet the string actually meant.

Comment: @Leandros.  If you do little benchmarking, you will see that String version is actually faster.  So, they are not the same, though they produce the same outcome.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak Please explain.

Comment: @Leandros. The `String` method uses a ThreadLocal cache to store internal `StringEncoders` and the lookup is nearly instantaneous.  The `Charset` method, has to create a new `StringEncoder` every time, and also massage the passed Charset. This makes it a much heavier operation.  Why is it done this way I don't know, and was hoping to find it in the answer to this question.  Hence I cannot deem this answer correct.  Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Its the same method. If you pass CharsetName than Charset is found by java classes later. Otherwise you provide Charset and it is no need to create it's object.

Its same differece as using constructor for Point(x, y) and Point(point)

Comment: No, it's not the same method.  In fact, if you follow the code it is quite different than calling different Point constructors